# Why is this Ruby code far faster than the equivalent C++ code?

Tags: c++, math

Recently I've been going through some easy project Euler problems and solving them in Ruby and C++.  But for [Problem 14](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) concerning the Collatz conjecture, my C++ code went on for about half an hour before I terminated it, though when I translated the code into Ruby, it solved it in nine seconds.

That difference is quite unbelievable to me - I had always been led to believe that C++ was almost always faster than Ruby, especially for mathematical process.

My code is as follows.

C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 0;
    while (b < 1000000)
    {

        a = b;
        int d = 2;
        while (a != 4)
        {
            if (a % 2 == 0)
                a /= 2;
            else
                a = 3*a + 1;
            d++;
        }
        if (d > c)
        {
            cout << b << ' ' << d << endl;
            c=d;
        }
        b++;
    }
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Run time - I honestly don't know, but it's a really REALLY long time.

and Ruby:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

    a = 0
    b = 2
    c = 0
    while b < 1000000
        a = b;
        d = 2
        while a != 4
            if a % 2 == 0
                a /= 2
            else
                 a = 3*a + 1
            end
            d+=1
        end
        if d > c
            p b,d
            c=d
        end
        b+=1
    end
    p c
```

Run time - approximately 9 seconds.

Any idea what's going on here?

P.S. the C++ code runs a good deal faster than the Ruby code until it hits 100,000.

Comment: Change that `endl` to `"\n"`, since it performs a flush of the stream and unbuffered IO is really slow.

Comment: How do you compile the C++?

Comment: will do, but when it gets to higher numbers it can be as much as a few minutes between prints and the difference of endl and "\n" becomes negligable

Comment: I build and run with codeblocks and mingw

Comment: makes me wonder, how would codeblocks/mingw executables compare perfromance-wise to a more native compiler like intel or msvc?

Comment: You also have a `std::cout` call in there. That would slow down the code too.

Comment: I like this question because the assumption was way out there. Shows much about assumptions!

Comment: This code is not equivalent and you don't even post your compiler settings.

Comment: The _instant_ I saw the question title I thought `std::endl`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're overflowing `int`, so it's not terminating. Use `int64_t` instead of `int` in your c++ code. 
You'll probably need to include `stdint.h` for that..

Comment: as far as i can tell that makes no noticeable difference

Comment: Improve your answer, explaining why he is overflowing int.

Comment: You're probaly on a 32 bit machine.. i updated my answer to use int64_t instead of long int.

Comment: buuuut, it looks like unsigned long did the trick, and in .539 seconds. i guess i should do more study on datatypes.

Comment: Specifically, `while (a != 4)` will never complete when `a` is large enough to overflow the math in that loop.

Comment: More specifically the loop when b=901118 seems to take a to the limits.

Comment: @hexist He can use long long too.

Comment: @eldersouth With `unsigned long`, if that is a 32-bit type, you have overflow too. Out of pure luck that doesn't lead to producing a wrong answer for the PE problem, but for other limits, it could.

Comment: don't worry, i'm on a 64 bit, so the world is all sunshine and rainbows

Comment: It's true that with an unsigned 32-bit var, the code can still overflow.  But the particularly buggy behaviour on signed 32-bit was probably caused by `a /= 2` preserving the sign bit on values that had overflowed to negative.  But, without looking too closely at the math, you're "probably" unlikely to get false matches comparing `a` with 4.  If it is equal to 4 modulo 2^32, it's "probably" equal.

Answer (score 3):

In your case the problem was a bug in C++ implementation (numeric overflow).

Note however that trading in some memory you can get the result much faster than you're doing...

Hint: suppose you find that from number 231 you need 127 steps to end the computation, and suppose that starting from another number you get to 231 after 22 steps... how many more steps do you need to do?

Comment: yeah, i thought about saving values into an array when d > 100 but then i thought, do i really want to check against a large array for every iteration of every number number under one million? I suppose that if i kept everything sorted and used a binary search and only checked once 'a' falls below a threshhold (probably 'b') it would make it run faster, but when it solves in half a second that just doesn't appeal to me, although i would do so if this were part of a larger program and was called often

Comment: What about storing the count for `b` into `count[b]`? No need to "search" ;-)

Comment: Is integer overflow really a *bug in C++ implementation*? Isn't it undefined behaviour?

Comment: @AlvinWong: It is a bug in the implementation of the algorithm. The bug is not considering integer overflow would happen with those numbers. When writing in C or C++ you simply are not expected to do integer overflow, if you do then your code is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

With 32-bit arithmetic, the C++ code overflows on `a = 3*a + 1`.  With signed 32-bit arithmetic, the problem is compounded, because the `a /= 2` line will preserve the sign bit.

This makes it much harder for `a` to ever equal 4, and indeed when `b` reaches 113383, `a` overflows and the loop never ends.

With 64-bit arithmetic there is no overflow, because `a` maxes out at 56991483520, when `b` is 704511.

Without looking at the math, I speculate that unsigned 32-bit arithmetic will "probably" work, because the multiplication and unsigned division will both work modulo 2^32.  And given the short running time of the program, values aren't going to cover too much of the 64-bit spectrum, so if a value is equal to 4 modulo 2^32, it's "probably" actually equal to 4.